# Mixing quoted and unquoted values in IN() condition - MySQL quirk or general issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL manual contains [the following interesting note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) about mixing quoted and unquoted values in an `IN` condition:

> You should never mix quoted and unquoted values in an IN() list because the comparison rules for quoted values (such as strings) and unquoted values (such as numbers) differ. Mixing types may therefore lead to inconsistent results.

However, it doesn't really explain why this is a problem.  It has examples, but it doesn't show either the data being queried or the results, so they only serve as illustrations without giving any explanation about the issue.

I have two questions:

1. **Why does this cause problems in MySQL?**  Ideally, provide an example where the results are wrong/inconsistent/unintuitive, to demonstrate.
2. **Is this a MySQL-specific quirk or does this apply to other database systems?**  In particular, I am interested in whether this issue affects SQL Server, but would ideally like the question answered in the general case.

Comment: "**may** therefore lead to inconsistent results". *May* doesn't mean *will*. *inconsistent* can mean many things. It could be "inconsistent" across platforms, versions or settings. It could also be "inconsistent" compared to analogical statements (`a IN (x, y)` should be the same as `a = x OR a = y`). As has been shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664793/mysql-unexpected-results-in-clause-number-string-on-a-varchar-column) - It seems, they have fixed this case, but left the documentation unchanged, because they don't want it to be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you consider "non-intuitive".  This returns false:

```
'00' in ('0', '01')
```

However, this returns true:

```
'00' in (0, '01')
```

Comment: You missed out the third combination, `'00' in (0, 1)`, which also returns true.  Your example therefore doesn't appear to be related to mixing quoted and unquoted variables, but a general point about type conversion, which is covered a few paragraphs earlier in the documentation.  The issue my question refers to is explicitly brought up separately to the general type conversion issue, so I would have thought there are specific additional issues that are encountered in this situation.

Comment: And, just for completeness, `0 in ('00', '01')` also returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I think the next few lines give an unintuitive example without mixing :

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' IN (0), 0 IN ('b');
        -> 1, 1
```

That you can extend :

```
SELECT 'a' IN (0, 1, '2'), 'a' IN ('0', '1', '2');
-> 1, 0
SELECT 0 IN (0.0, 'b'), 0 IN ('0.0', 'b');
-> 1, 1
```

Also there is [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664793/mysql-unexpected-results-in-clause-number-string-on-a-varchar-column?lq=1) :

> In MySQL, why does the following query return '----', '0', '000', 'AK3462', 'AL11111', 'C131521', 'TEST', etc.?
>
> `select varCharColumn from myTable where varCharColumn in (-1, '');`
>
> I get none of these results when I do:
>
> `select varCharColumn from myTable where varCharColumn in (-1);`
>
> `select varCharColumn from myTable where varCharColumn in ('');`

Everything is cast into float, most likely, according to [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) :

> [...] In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes places as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

And string are cast as 0.0, unless they start by digits. Also from the same link, there could be problems with floating point accuracy, and queries not using index because the type is not right (it must cast everything to float, so no index usage, I guess).

I think you might get something similar but not the same with every DBMS because you have to cast things to compare them. It might not be the exact same issue in SQL Server, because the data type precedence is not the same, but you should compare data of the same data type.
[According to this link that gives data type precedence for SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/implicit-conversion-in-sql-server/) :

> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

int and string would be cast to int (not float) for a SQL server DBMS.

Comment: I don't know that this answer quite explains the problem.  The linked-to question is, I think, exhibiting the same problem that I am talking about but as the accepted answer simply quotes the paragraph that I quote in my question, it doesn't provide any illumination about why this is a specific issue beyond the standard type-casting rules.

Comment: Yours questions are "Why does this cause problems in MySQL?", and "Is this a MySQL-specific quirk or does this apply to other database systems?". I can not see anything in your question about the type-casting rules. Maybe the answer is simply because there are type-casting rules,

Comment: And I did not linked the answer to the other question, but the question itself where some says "I have thoses results, the results are wrong/inconsistent/unintuitive". You were asking for examples, that is why I only pasted this part of the question, because I think it is a good example. Not everyone knows what are the standard type-casting rules.

Answer (score 0):

Running some simple tests seems that the control between data types is done correctly, despite what is written in the MySQL manual.

```
SELECT 0 IN ('0','00',0,00); -> TRUE
SELECT 0 IN ('0','01',1,01); -> TRUE
SELECT 0 IN ('1','00',1,10); -> TRUE
SELECT 0 IN ('11','10',0,10); -> TRUE
SELECT 0 IN ('1','01',1,00); -> TRUE
SELECT '0' IN ('1','01',1,00); -> TRUE
SELECT '0' IN ('0','00',0,00); -> TRUE
SELECT '0' IN ('0','01',1,01); -> TRUE
SELECT '0' IN ('1','00',1,10); -> FALSE
SELECT '0' IN ('11','10',0,10); -> TRUE
SELECT '1' IN ('11','10',1,10); -> TRUE
SELECT '15.32' IN ('11','10',1,15.32); -> TRUE
SELECT 13.12 IN ('11','10',1,13.12); -> TRUE
SELECT 00 IN ('11','00',1,13.12); -> TRUE
SELECT '00' IN ('11',00,1,13.12); -> TRUE
SELECT '00.0' IN ('11',00.0,1,13.12); -> TRUE
SELECT '00.00' IN ('11',0,1,13.12); -> TRUE
SELECT '00.01' IN ('11',0.01,1,13.12); -> TRUE
```

The above results can be seen in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/137416)

But the above tests are not even close to testing all the different data types of MySQL.

In addition we should simply just think in what cases we would use the `IN ()` operator.

MySQL writes that mixed data types offer surprises on results sometimes, but then again **is it actually needed to have different data types inside** `IN ()`?

In short **no**. What will be checked against the values inside the parenthesis will be a table column having specific data type.

For example doesn't comparing a column of `TEXT` against `IN ('Hello','World',13)` seems odd? I know that one could oppose the fact that in the column having data type `TEXT` you may have numerical values. Good, then just write the above like this `IN ('Hello','World','13')` since we were speaking about a `TEXT` column.

In case that we did not know the data type or if somehow the data type is dynamic and could some times change, then we should convert that field to the data type that we expect the majority of results would be.

Comment: Interesting analysis - so you are saying that what the manual says is incorrect, and that (beyond the standard type-conversion) there is no additional reason to avoid this?

Comment: Also, re: your question, "is it actually needed to have different data types?" - my question arose due to dynamic code, whereby IN() statements are being generated by a `QuoteList()` function, which creates the statement from an array. Therefore, yes, it is quite possible (and, in fact, not uncommon) for the supplied array to have mixed types; Whether or not it's needed, it happens. Quite a lot! My question arises because I want to know whether I need to adapt `QuoteList()` to normalise the quoting style, as the manual suggests and, if so, what problem I would be solving by doing this.

Comment: @HappyDog no i am not saying that the manual is incorrect i say that for simple examples you won't get `hurt` and that your results will be accurate. But regarding the second comment, i mean that if the column is `VARCHAR` why to compare it with an `INT` you may get correct result but is it accurate all the way? No.

Comment: @HappyDog perhaps you could use `MySQL QUOTE()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote to the values that are populated as numbers. Example, `SELECT...WHERE column_name IN ('HELLO',QUOTE(13))` or `SELECT...WHERE QUOTE(column_name) IN ('1','2','3')`. Take a look to some more examples here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/137433 (check the last ones...)

Comment: Yes - I could!  The point of my question is to find out whether I my DB abstraction layer should be doing this automatically or whether this is a userland problem to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @HappyDog i think if you check the example you will understand that it is done up to a very good point by the db driver abstraction layer. Since the vendor indicates that it is not fail safe then an easy task to do is to watch what datatypes you use in cases of `IN(...)`.. Perhaps you need to re-think all of your db logic, If data are dynamic and mixed perhaps there is a logic in splitting them by type if this is to provide accuracy in the result.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why does this cause problems in MySQL?**

The example below should be able to show you the inconsistency about using IN across quoted `(x='1a')` and unquoted types `(x=1)`. Note for the same value of x = 1, the same IN expression yields 0 in Query 1, but yields 1 in Query 2.

```sql
SELECT
  x, x IN ('1b','a1')
FROM
  (
    select '1a' as x
    union all select 1
  ) q1;

SELECT
  x, x IN ('1b','a1')
FROM
  (
    select 1 as x
  ) q1;
```

Results:

```
Query 1:
'1a': 0
1: 0

Query 2:
1: 1
```

For far I cannot observe inconsistency if I only alter the list inside IN. But I observed that pattern is like:

expr IN (...array of values)

For expr **with** string, against **string** values: compare as **string**
For expr without string, against **string** values: compare as number
For expr **with**  string, against numeric values: compare as number
For expr without string, against numeric values: compare as  number

**2. Is this a MySQL-specific quirk or does this apply to other database systems?**

Case by case. For MSSQL I tell you no because when comparing string with number, they give you an error message like:
`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1a' to data type int.`

Comment: I awarded this question the bounty as it was the best answer received before the deadline. However, on close reading I can see that it doesn't really answer the question at all, as in the examples all values of the `IN()` statement have the same quote style and are simply demonstrating the type-casting issue talked about elsewhere....

Comment: (cont) ...The response to the second point, as a general 'it depends', is probably true, but again the example shows a type mismatch between the left-hand expression and the `IN()` values; nothing to do with mixed `IN()` values (though I concede that mixed values will trigger this error if there needs to be an exact type match, as expr can't have more than one type).

Comment: @HappyDog Yes but this is the conclusion...If you find mixing values for IN() does cause an inconsistency, I will be interested to know too :)

Comment: @HappyDog As I am not able to find inconsistency by altering things inside IN(), I tried to alter it outside and there is a true inconsistency found. Now, we cannot tell whether `1 IN ('1b','a1')` is true or false due to the inconsistency. Again, I agree the IN() values does not NEED TO merge types in my example.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why does this cause problems in MySQL?**
Engine needs to know how it will make comparisons.
If you compare column with integers, the column integer value will be compared with the IN list. If IN list items are strings, comparison will differ.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

**2. Is this a MySQL-specific quirk or does this apply to other database systems?**
It is not MYSQL specific. For performance reasons (indexing) it is always better not to make casting.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question as it doesn't address the point about a single `IN()` statement containing both quoted and unquoted values.  Your second point about performance considerations is probably a fairly important point but is somewhat tangential as my question is about behavioural differences.

Comment: @HappyDog IN is shorter way of several OR clauses for the same column. If you quote values, they will be considered as strings. So if you make comparison with the int column you should not quote values. The worst case would be mixing quoted and unquoted values. In that case the engine can't return consistent results. So, all comparisons should be done with the same type.

Answer (score -1):

> Why does this cause problems in MySQL?

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Basically it's about how the database handles the field comparison. In particular, MySQL automatically converts the string value to a numeric value when comparing the numeric with string values. Since MySQL is [written in C++](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) , somewhere in the code base, they should cast the string value to `double` prior to field comparison.

There is nothing special about the `IN` clause, I think. In the MySQL source code, I saw comments similar to this one:

```sh
    `WHERE a IN (b, c)` can also be rewritten as `WHERE a = b OR a = c`
```

Which makes sense and `IN` is (probably) treated the same way in code base. So based on this, if we have let's say something like this:

```sql
... WHERE '04.2' IN ('0', 4.2);
```

Which means `'04.2' = '0' OR '04.2' = 4.2`, and will return true, because, in C/C++:

```c
"04.2" =  "0"  // string value comparison -> false
cast_as_double("04.2") = 4.2 // double value comparison -> true
```

The same applies for other cases, which resolve as true, e.g. `42 IN ('0042', 0)`, `'3.00' IN (3, '1')`, `0 IN (3, '0.00')` etc.

> Is this a MySQL-specific quirk or does this apply to other database systems?

This seems to be the case with other databases as well. If you like, you can test them online

- MySQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com
- PostgreSQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com
- MS SQL Server 2017: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/12807

Comment: I disagree with this answer and am down-voting as I think it is wholly incorrect.  If `WHERE a IN (b, c)` was equivalent to `WHERE a = b OR a = c' then there would be no need for the paragraph I quoted in the question, which is stating the complete opposite of this.

Comment: @HappyDog thanks for your feedback. I think it's a matter of opinion. I just (right now) saw the comment from @PaulSpiegel, which basically says the same thing. For me, *mixing* means, that you have different types within your `IN()` clause, as if you had an array that contains strings and numbers, thus *mixed*. I don't think that my answer is "wholly incorrect" - but quite the converse.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I have just posted as this may give a bit more of a concrete example.  My point is that there seems to be something else *beyond* the basic issues of mixing data types that your answer (and, in fact, all the other answers) describe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed took a look at your example. I also gave my feedback to your answer. Please don't get me wrong, but I get the impression that you're not looking for an answer here, but for something mysterious, which doesn't exist. It's all about casting - period. If you really want to understand as why this happens, then I would suggest you to study the MySQL source code  which I originally linked in my answer.

Comment: See my response to your comment.  I've realised that this is probably a version issue that may not affect more recent MySQL versions, and in the light of that I'm removing my downvote.

Comment: Actually - turns out I can't undo my downvote unless the question gets edited.  If you are able to make an edit, then I'll remove it, but otherwise not much I can do, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst there have been a lot of lot of answers and comments that provide examples of 'unintuitive' behaviour, most of these examples seem to be explained by the standard casting rules.  In other words, the results were entirely consistent with what would be returned from `SELECT A = B;` for the given `A` and `B`.

*"Because casting"* doesn't seem like a particularly satisfying explanation for the paragraph I quoted in the question.  That paragraph comes *after* a number of paragraphs explaining how type conversion affects the `IN()` statement, so it seems somewhat repetitive and redundant if that is all it's referring to.

My interpretation of the quoted paragraph is that it is an explicit statement that `a IN(b, c)` may give different results to `a = b OR a = c` in situations where `b` and `c` are quoted differently.

I was therefore looking to find an example where the result couldn't be explained by the usual casting rules.

I think the reason that we haven't seen a good example yet is because most answers focussed on comparing numbers, in string and non-string representations.  However, by basing the test around string values instead, I have managed to construct a non-intuitive example that is not explained by simple type conversion rules and which is not equivalent to the individual comparisons ORed together; the comparison between `'test'` and `23` gives different results depending on what other values are in the `IN()` list:

```
SELECT 'test' IN('fish');       --> 0
SELECT 'test' IN(23);           --> 0
SELECT 'test' IN('fish', 23);   --> 1 !!!
```

I have yet to come up with a good explanation about what is happening here - is there some rule being followed, or is it just a MySQL quirk?  I also haven't got an answer to the second question, as that somewhat depends on the reason for the behaviour (e.g. if it is defined by the standard or is an artefact of an obvious optimisation, vs. just being a MySQL-specific quirk) but I guess this could be figured out by running the above test on other RDBMSs.

Any comments to help flesh this out (or answers that cover the missing elements) will be appreciated - I will update this answer with any further details that I manage to deduce and don't plan on accepting any answer (including my own) until I understand what's going on a little bit better.

Comment: Just for this test `SELECT 'test' IN('fish', 23);   --> 1 !!!` that you claim it should be true, I spun up a MySQL (docker) container to test it. Well I was **not** surprised, it returns **0** not a **1**. It is simple and all about the casting as I explained in my answer in detail. Why do you refuse to accept and understand this? Downvoting this answer, as it contains an incorrect test result.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I've just realised I was testing on an older MySQL version (5.0) I've retested on the most recent version I have to hand (5.7) and this does, indeed, return 0, not 1.  I wonder, therefore, whether this is a documentation bug!  The quoted paragraph exists in the [documentation for 5.0](http://web.archive.org/web/20100214095603/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) so perhaps it was added when this genuine issue existed but was never subsequently removed...

Comment: Why do you use an ancient version of MySQL? The min. recommended version is `5.5`, and right now the version `8.0.X` is already out there...

Comment: And even with MySQL v5.5 `SELECT 'test' IN('fish', 23); ` returns **0**.

Comment: I don't, generally, just happened to be what was installed on the machine I was using for my testing.

Comment: According to Wikipedia MySQL `v5.0` was a beta-release and had lots of issues which were fixed in the production release `v5.5` later on. So it would be a miracle that `v5.0` is still being used in any project - for whatever purpose it may be.

Comment: It isn't being used in any projects.  Also, it would be wrong to assume that this issue only existed in 5.0, and not in 4.x or earlier, without doing a bit more investigation (which, personally, I don't plan on doing).